# What is good to do with exception when logging?

Tags: java, exception, logging

Suppose I want to reflect exception in the log.

Should I pass stack trace into `log.error()` or just Exception's `toString()`? Or do something better?

How to obtain stack trace string to pass to logger?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All modern logging frameworks treat passed `Exception` object special:

```
log.error("Danger! High Voltage!", ex);
```

The framework (let it be [logback](/questions/tagged/logback) or [log4j](/questions/tagged/log4j)) will format the stack trace nicely for you. Always log the full stack trace unless you *really* know what you are doing. Otherwise you can always filter out exceptions from given logger.

Also note that many important exception do not provide meaningful message, `NullPointerException` being important example.

Comment: +1 for learning me the tags in the answer using `[tag:java]`!

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux: yep, I really like this feature, see also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123799

Answer (score 1):

I would go for logging the whole stack trace of course. It's much easier to find it source this way.

I don't know what library you are using for logging but if it does not support to log exceptions, you can get the stacktrace as a string this way:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(baos);
exception.printStackTrace(ps);
ps.close();
String stacktrace = baos.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

When using something like [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/), there is an extra parameter for the exception so you typically write something like this:

```
catch(Exception e){
    logger.error("some message", e);
}
```

Log4j will take care of printing the stacktrace.

One thing to keep in mind (at least for log4j) is this: When you don't want to log a message but only the exception, you must use:

```
logger.error("", e);
```

not

```
logger.error(e); // bad usage! This uses e.toString()!!
```